# Removing duplicate geometries in Shapely

Tags: python, duplicates, geometry, shapely

I have a list of Shapely polygons. From that list I want to extract only unique polygons removing the duplicates.

How to do it in a faster way? (My list contains thousands of polygons)

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

lists = [[(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)], [(6,6),(7,7),(8,8),(9,9)], [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)]]
polys = [Polygon(item) for item in lists] ##This is given condition

for poly in polys:

    test = [p.intersects(poly) for p in polys] ##Return true or false
    print test


[True, False, True]
[False, True, False]
[True, False, True]
```

The expected result is:

```
[[(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)], [(6,6),(7,7),(8,8),(9,9)]]
```

Comment: Why use `intersects`? Shouldn't you use `p.equals(poly)` to find duplicate geometries?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that you should not use [`intersects()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.intersects), as that will identify any polygons that overlap at all as duplicates. Use [`equals()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.equals) instead.

You can create a list that stores the unique polygons, and then for each polygon in your list, loop over the polygons stored in the outer list, and if none of them are equal to the new one, add this to the list, you can use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function for that.

Example:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

lists = [[(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)], [(6,6),(7,7),(8,8),(9,9)], [(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)]]
polys = [Polygon(item) for item in lists] ##This is given condition
uniqpolies = []
for poly in polys:

    if not any(p.equals(poly) for p in uniqpolies):
        uniqpolies.append(poly)
```

From [documentation on `any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

> Return `True` if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return `False`.

Comment: Is it also possible to return the results directly with out collecting in the list?

Comment: Without the other list, you would have to loop through them yourself. And its correct - `for p in uniqpoies` .

Comment: Just a note that you should not use intersects(), as that will identify any polygons that overlap at all as duplicates. As @Mike T above suggested, use equals().